# Bash - replacing variable value via Regex does not yield expected result

Tags: string, bash

I'm currently trying to automate my jellyfin library.
I want to write a small script that moves the processed movies into a folder with the same name as the movie.
The catch is that I have multiple versions per movie denoted with a dash (e.g `Moviename - av1.webm`).
I can't get bash to accept my regex for replacing this  `- av1.webm` part at the end.

Every other Regex checker/other program that uses regex matches with the pattern i used: `( - av1)?*\.webm`

Note: I do not need a complete solution to this problem. I just want to know why bash processes this Regex differently and what I need to look out for in the future.

Thank you.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.webm; do 
J=${i/( - av1)*\.webm/}
echo $J
mkdir "$J"; 
mv "$i" "$J";
done
```

expected outcome:

1. Folder with the same name as the movie but without any postfixes (these are hardcoded) and no file extension ist created
2. File is moved to that folder

actual outcome:

```
Moviename - av1.mkv
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Moviename - av1.mkv’: File exists
```

Comment: In parameter expansions, bash uses pattern matching, not regular expressions. Probably you want for `J=${i% - *.webm}`. See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: `J="${i/% - *.webm/}"`also seems to work (at least for the given example)

Comment: Are you aware that you have ... ( - av1)?*\.webm ... in your question, but you have ... ( - av1)*\.webm ... in your script snippet  (missing question mark)?  Those will **NOT** match the same patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script demonstrating the forms of the command to obtain a different "root" of filenames to create the directory for depositing your files.

```
#!/bin/bash

cases="{names.list}"

cat >"${cases}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
ABC.webm
ABC - av1.webm
bad - av1 yadda.webm
dum - av1.webm
DEF - av1 .webm
DEF - av1 jumbo.webm
crap - av1.webm
EnDoFiNpUt

while read line
do
    touch "${line}"
done <"${cases}"

for i in *.webm
do 
    echo -e "\n FILE:  '${i}' ..."
    # MODE 1 - strip suffix
    J="${i%.*}"
    echo "MODE 1: '${J}'"

    # MODE 2 - strip fixed pattern
    J="${i% - av1\.webm}"
    echo "MODE 2: '${J}'"

    # MODE 3 - strip variable pattern
    J="${i% - av1*\.webm}"
    echo "MODE 3: '${J}'"

#   mkdir "${J}"
#   echo mv "${i}" "${J}"
done
```

Session log is as follows:

```
 FILE:  'ABC - av1.webm' ...
MODE 1: 'ABC - av1'
MODE 2: 'ABC'
MODE 3: 'ABC'

 FILE:  'ABC.webm' ...
MODE 1: 'ABC'
MODE 2: 'ABC.webm'
MODE 3: 'ABC.webm'

 FILE:  'bad - av1 yadda.webm' ...
MODE 1: 'bad - av1 yadda'
MODE 2: 'bad - av1 yadda.webm'
MODE 3: 'bad'

 FILE:  'crap - av1.webm' ...
MODE 1: 'crap - av1'
MODE 2: 'crap'
MODE 3: 'crap'

 FILE:  'DEF - av1 jumbo.webm' ...
MODE 1: 'DEF - av1 jumbo'
MODE 2: 'DEF - av1 jumbo.webm'
MODE 3: 'DEF'

 FILE:  'DEF - av1 .webm' ...
MODE 1: 'DEF - av1 '
MODE 2: 'DEF - av1 .webm'
MODE 3: 'DEF'

 FILE:  'dum - av1.webm' ...
MODE 1: 'dum - av1'
MODE 2: 'dum'
MODE 3: 'dum'
```